# Upload image from devide to FTP using android app

Tags: android, web, upload, ftp, imageview

Hey I have a code that let the user pick an image from the gallery and after he chooses the image is shown in an image view, now when the user click a button it should upload the image to ftp server , but from some reason the app tells me that the location of the file I am giving is not found.

here is the ftp upload code (I execute it using asynctask)

```
    public UploadImage(String host,int port,String username,String password,String imagePath) {


    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;

}

    public  void uploadingFilestoFtp() throws IOException
{
    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect(host);

        if (con.login(username, password))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(this.imagePath);
            String data = uri.getPath();

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/img.png", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

and the loading file to imageview

```
   loadedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upload_image1);
    Drawable drawable = loadedImage.getDrawable();
    if(drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_icon).getConstantState())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SelectPicture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {


             selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            loadedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upload_image1);
            loadedImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Glide.with(this).load(selectedImageURI)
                    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upload_image1));

            ImageView m =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.remove_image);
            m.setFocusable(true);
            m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

The imagePath String is the image uri converted to string.
can anyone help me and tell me why isn't it finding the file?

Comment: Well which file is not found? Exact full path please. Or full uri. `The imagePath String is the image uri converted to string.`. Well show us the value!

Comment: If you let the user select a file you dont have to put it in an imageview first. You can directly upload the file.

Comment: `UploadImage(String host,int port,String username,String password,String imagePath)`. Show us the value of parameter `imagePath`  when you call this function.

Comment: `new File(data))`. You use that as a parameter value. You better take it out like `File file = new File(data));`. And then check if the file really exists with `if (!file.existst()) return null;`. But yet better: check if the file exists before you call the async task

Answer (score 0):

Ask user to pick the image and use that image to imageView.. the `path` consist of the actual image path you can upload it..

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null)
            {
                path = uri.toString();
                if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
                {
                    // Selected file/directory path is below
                    path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
                }
                else{
                    path =  getRealPathFromUri(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                }

            }
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope you are giving permission also

Comment: And your `getRealPathFromUri();` is an outdated function. Should not be needed. And if you keep using it you should let return it a`null` if there is a catch. Which will happen most of the time nowadays.

Comment: @greenapps : Okkay.. I am using this in my apps and getting the result thats why i posted the code!! and Thank you for the update!

Comment: But i do not understand why you posted this as an answer. OP wants to upload a file to an FTP server. OP did not have any problem to put the file in an imageview.

Comment: @greenapps the same issue occurs to me.. Loading in image view but on upload says file not found.. when i researched I found that some paths starts with 'file://' and some with other! I dont know why! Someone suggested me this code! And it works as espected..

Comment: I dont know whether it will help him, But as it helped me i thought may be he can workaround a bit and make his working

Comment: What does it matter if a path starts with "file://" ? Just remove it if you need it for a `File` object! OP cannot make it working with your code as as you said it cannot upload from your path too.

Comment: @greenapps tried that! Still the error was there! Again as i told that i dont know why? it changes depends on where we are selecting images(gallery, recents files etc)